# How do I mirror any VCS unique to Ubuntu?

Tags: server, package-management, git

I'm a student at UWyo researching source code differences. I've been cloning git repositories from distributions conforming to the following:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/apt/lists/* | grep Vcs-Git | awk '{print $2}' > ~/apt-sources
```

I'd like to know for the engineers out there if it's feasible to simply mirror the git server running things (not the package mirror). I know most of the packages are actually upstream in debian. . . but some things do change as they get contributed.

How would I approach mirroring that server?
What are some of your outputs to that command?

Comment: Not an answer, only a hint for an all-in-one-command: replace your command with `sudo awk '/Vcs-Git/ {print $2}' /var/lib/apt/lists/* > ~/apt-sources`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not mirror the servers, you can clone the projects.

Use the `awk` command below for a dry run

```
find /var/lib/apt/lists/ -type f ! -name "*.gpg" ! -name "lock" -exec  awk '/Vcs-Git/ {print "git clone "$2}' {} \; | sort -u
```

*Sample output*

```
git clone https://gitlab.uncompleted.org/debian/postfwd.git
git clone https://gitlab.uncompleted.org/debian/ps-watcher.git
git clone https://git.torproject.org/debian/tor.git
git clone http://smarden.org/git/bcron.git/
git clone http://smarden.org/git/dash.git/
git clone http://smarden.org/git/ipsvd.git/
git clone http://smarden.org/git/twoftpd.git/
git clone http://smarden.org/git/ucspi-tcp.git/
git clone https://mod.gnutls.org/mod_gnutls
git clone https://repo.or.cz/r/git/debian.git/
git clone https://www.github.com/ioerror/tlsdate/
git clone http://tcosproject.org/git/p910nd.git
git clone http://tcosproject.org/git/tcosconfig.git
git clone http://tcosproject.org/git/tcos-configurator.git
git clone http://tcosproject.org/git/tcosmonitor.git
git clone http://uv-cdat.llnl.gov/git/cmip5-cmor-tables.git
git clone http://www.project-moonshot.org/git/moonshot.git
git clone http://www.project-moonshot.org/git/moonshot-ui.git
```

and this command to clone the repositories, in my case **11,818**

```
mkdir -p ~/src
mkdir -p ~/src/mirror
cd ~/src/mirror
find /var/lib/apt/lists/ -type f ! -name "*.gpg" ! -name "lock" -exec  awk '/Vcs-Git/ {system("git clone "$2)}' {} \; | sort -u
```

Comment: Understood. I have already done so for 194 GB of source code a week ago :D ^u^.

Comment: @CameronWhiting As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code that's actually packaged in Ubuntu, patches and all, then they're on [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/), easily cloned using [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/). All you need to know is the name of the source package of any given package.

Then you can do:

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu/<source-package-name>
```

Adapting the code you used:

```
awk '/Source/{print $2}' /var/lib/apt/lists/*Packages | 
 sort -u | 
 xargs -i bzr branch lp:ubuntu/{}
```